# Excel formatting/Highlight row based on the last date and equal cell value

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

My question relates with the following.

I have a matrix in Excel of values, I want to highlight the entire row if two conditions are met. Those conditions are:

a. For equal values on column A compare its date;

b. If the value is equal, highlight the row with the most recent date.

Graphically its the following:

```
    A   B
1   Y   04-08-2006

2   X   02-07-2008

3   X   12-05-2014

4   Z   09-08-2014

5   X   25-06-2016

6   Z   01-04-2018

7   Y   24-07-2018

8   X   25-09-2018
```

I want to highlight the 6, 7 and 8 row with different colors.

Can I do that with conditional formatting or its not possible and the only way is to write code in VBA?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you researched / tried, so far? [It looks like no attempt has been made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. Make a small Pivot table where your column A is the rows and columns B are the values set to max. Then add a columns that is a `vlookup` to add the max date for each group (formula show in image) and finally just add conditional formatting, one rule per group again as shown in the image (note in this case the formatting is applied to the range `A1:C9`

[image]

You can always hide column D and the pivot table or put them on another sheet if need be.

Comment: Ok, this can be a solution, but what happens if I had more variables below or more entries? 
I'll always have to add a new value on the pivot table?

Comment: @Focha... no the pivot table will do that for you. Just select A:C as it's range. You will have to right click on the pivot table and click refresh when your data change but that's less intrusive than having to run VBA. If you add a new option in A then you will have to make a new conditional formatting rule (because you want a new colour). Also you can add a check to see if the cell is not blank in your conditional formatting and then also apply it to range A:C.